# check if the user has logged in with social account - Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

in the web site that i'm working on , I have an authetication system and I'm using django allauth at the same time so the user can login with his gmail or facebook account if he wants . how can I check in the template if the user has logged in with his facebook/gmail account ?
i want somthing like this

```
{% if user not 'use his facebook or gmail'  %}                     
    <a href="{% some url %}">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">somthing </button>
      </a> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please share of your relevant code so we can help you figure out where you are stuck.

Comment: check my modification i hope you'll understand what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've found this and it has done what I needed

```
 {% load socialaccount %}
    
  {% get_social_accounts user as accounts %}
  {% if accounts %} "if the user has logged in using his facebook account or his google account"

          "do somthing here"
        
  {% endif %}
```

for more details check [the documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html) of django-allauth

Answer (score 2):

for future readers, in `view.py` you do can something like this to detect if user is a social user or not

```
is_social = user.socialaccount_set.exists()
```

*it returns **True** if your logged in with `facebook/google/...`
else it return **False***

Comment: with no imports: user.socialaccount_set.exists()